# How to properly set up fullcalendar week view?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I want to make a weekly schedule with fullcalendario[text](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view).Monthly view works perfectly fine, but for some reason the week view is not loading; all that i get is white blank page. I have used their sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
        import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
        const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [timeGridPlugin],
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay' // user can switch between the two
        }
        })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have read their documentation about seeting up the calendar, but it got me nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your container `calendarEl`

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
```

and also render finally

```
calendar.render();
```

use within document ready function,

```
        import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
        import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [timeGridPlugin],
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay' 
        }
        })
      calendar.render()
```

Comment: I have just added it, but the page ist still blank. I have put it right after the imports.

Comment: Use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {});`